# Unable to open files by dragging them into applications opened from Conemu

Tags: conemu

I was wondering, why I'm not able to drag files to applications opened by Conemu, like for example emacs, firefox, etc..

How could be this enabled?

Thanks

UPDATE:

I've uploaded a video to illustrate the issue:
[Video](http://clients.tourvista.co.uk/vt/zip/tmp/conemu/conemu_x264.mp4)

Comment: It is enabled. For example, notepad++ accepts files.

Comment: Well, I've tried with Firefox,Chrome,IE,Eclipse,PowershellISE and Gvim and none of them opened the file when I drag it. If I open any of this programs in a normal way, they all open the file :-) So I must be missing something.

Comment: I don't think it matters, but I should have said that I'm using Cmder, and I have this problem when I open a program both using Powershell or CMD consoles.

Comment: OK,just checked IE. Drop is working. Unless you tell us what exactly you are trying to do - nobody can tell you what you are doing wrong.

Comment: And of course you need to check official latest ConEmu build.

Comment: Thank you. Updated question by adding a video. I hope that helps.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that if you run chrome from PS started **outside**  of ConEmu the result will be the same. If so ConEmu is not a part of the question. In other words you open chrome from PS, but not from ConEmu!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that this is nothing to do with ConEmu or Powershell. It's Windows! :-)

Apparently if I open an application as an Administrator, then I'm not allowed to drag files into this application by design and for security reasons.

```
This is how the UAC works. Drag- and Drop are messages. And sending messages 
from a program with normal rights, to an application with admin rights can 
cause security issue.

Do Drag & Drop only work with application with the same rights (program 
with Admin rights to program with admin rights or program with normal rights to
program with normal rights ).
```

Source: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/cba0e9b1-25f8-40e5-a888-1435d604f68d/run-as-administrator-prevents-drag-and-drop-working